# Change menu buttons without reload site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually my menu looks like [this](http://jsbin.com/OsOXEzU/18/), in the end my navbar should look like this: 
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-breadcrumb-navigation
I can't use it because I can't load thems .js.. It just dosen't works well.

So I'm trying to write it alone, mechanice:

[image]

What is the best way to write it? I can easily make hover on div, but button need to stay hover to the next click without load site.

PS-Buttons have irregular shape so we need to use background-image on divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is pretty much solved by using CSS with your javascript plugin.

Notice that your javascript plugin automatically assign `ui-state-active` on the tabs that you clicked. By using this you can set the css style:

```
li.ui-state-active > a {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x25/c3a3f3/ffffff) !important;
}
```

Change accordingly to your background image.

If you need to remove the default orange border, which is an `outline` attribute on `:focus`, just set it none. This should be sufficient.

```
a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

or use this

```
a, a:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

to make sure it doesn't appear on any `a` tag.

Comment: Nice one, but it doesn't works on background-image: url(' ').

Comment: Add `!important` directive, see above my updated answer. Here is the working link to your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/OsOXEzU/25

Comment: Perfect it works very well. Do you have an idea for that border witch is already on current button? that's orange border. border: none; doesnt works

Comment: ok! If you can see for while, I add outline:none;, but this shows for a while every click http://jsbin.com/OsOXEzU/29/

Comment: I have updated the answer again. See this to make sure that orange border never appear again: http://jsbin.com/OsOXEzU/32/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can define your hover style to a class and assign that class to the divs on hover with jquery. Until next hover, it stays and when mouse enters to another div, you can remove it.
Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".menu.div").mouseenter(function(){
$(".menu.div").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```